# For Datastax NodeJS Cassandra Driver 3.5, what is the default ReconnectionPolicy?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-node-driver

We are using Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 with Node.js, using the Datastax NodeJS driver 3.5. Unfortunately, the documentation is often less than helpful. I cannot tell from everything I've read so far, what is the default ReconnectionPolicy if you don't specify one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default reconnection policy is `ExponentialReconnectionPolicy` with base delay of 1 seconds, and max delay of 600 seconds... It's [defined](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/lib/policies/index.js#L46) in the same file as [other default policies](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/lib/policies/index.js)...